# What happens if you start a service with a different Intent object each time

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-mediaplayer

There is a question in stack overflow that addresses what happens if you create a new intent object and use it to call the same service multiple times. So let us say we have this service class for a Media Player.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
   private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
     .....
     return  START_STICKY;
    }

    .....
}
```

So If we were to do

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

for the first time, it would call the onCreate method, instantiate our Media Player object and then call our onStartCommand method.

If we then call

```
startService(i);
```

again, it would simply call the onStartCommand method and not onCreate method.

**Question:**

But what if we did

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(i2);
```

Would it then call the onCreate method, create a 2nd MediaPlayer object in which now we have 2 Media Player objects and then call the onStartCommand method, or would it realized that we had already started the service before and would only call the onStartCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:
Would it then call the onCreate method, create a 2nd MediaPlayer object in which now we have 2 Media Player objects and then call the onStartCommand method?**

**No it wont**

Becoz service are single Instance in android no matter what Intent you start it with it is always be started once only as long as you are starting the same service

Answer (score 2):

> Would it then call the onCreate method, create a 2nd MediaPlayer object in which now we have 2 Media Player objects and then call the onStartCommand method

No.

> would it realized that we had already started the service before and would only call the onStartCommand?

Yes.

The `Intent` object is a carrier of data. The instance of the `Intent` object itself is meaningless. Both `i` and `i2` resolve to `MyService`, and at most there will be one running instance of `MyService`.

Answer (score 0):

It will call the onCreate method, create a 2nd MediaPlayer object in which now we have 2 Media Player objects and then call the onStartCommand method.